# How to search within opened Shapes in Visio

Tags: visio

I have downloaded Online Shapes "Microsoft Azure Cloud Icons"

[image]

But I am not able to search within it

[image]

Since there are dozens of icons it's very hard to work with it. I am using Desktop version of Visio. Any idea?

Comment: Your question is not for this forum, please try ask at [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-visio) or at official M$FT forums

Answer (score 0):

```
But I am not able to search within it
```

Can you change where you find?

[image]

Comment: No, it search only the installable package, but not within the already installed shapes

Comment: Sorry, I cant check it. I have very old Visio version without online search…